# StatelessWidgets vs. StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

All of the code for `StatelessWidget`s is in one class, even the `build` method. For `StatefulWidget`s, why is the `State` a separate class from the `Widget`? Couldn't they be combined and the `StatefulWidget` could just call `setState` on itself?

Comment: see http://takyam-git.github.io/flutter.github.io/tutorial/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StatefulWidget` class is immutable and stores its constructor arguments in `final` members. It is thrown away when its configuration information changes and replaced with a new `StatefulWidget`. This operation is generally very cheap, and triggers a rebuild.

By contrast, the associated `State` of a `StatefulWidget` can be long-lived. The `State` is re-used when the `StatefulWidget` is replaced, even if the constructor arguments changed, as long as the tree structure and keys match. This allows you to keep your `State` from being blown away even though the parent changed something about the `StatefulWidget`. For example, you might want to change the color or text of a widget while it's in the middle of an animation, and the `State` will notice because it uses the `widget` getter to read these values. (This is why a `State` must never have any constructor arguments; it must use `widget` to read its configuration.)

You can be notified of what changed in [`didUpdateWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) in case you want to provide special handling for the case where the `StatefulWidget` was reconfigured, although often simply being rebuilt will give the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:
[Design discussion](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/build.html)

> Putting a Widget build(BuildContext context) method on State rather putting a Widget build(BuildContext context, State state) method on StatefulWidget gives developers more flexibility when subclassing StatefulWidget.
>
> For example, AnimatedWidget is a subclass of StatefulWidget that introduces an abstract Widget build(BuildContext context) method for its subclasses to implement. If StatefulWidget already had a build method that took a State argument, AnimatedWidget would be forced to provide its State object to subclasses even though its State object is an internal implementation detail of AnimatedWidget.
>
> Conceptually, StatelessWidget could also be implemented as a subclass of StatefulWidget in a similar manner. If the build method were on StatefulWidget rather than State, that would not be possible anymore.
>
> Putting the build function on State rather than StatefulWidget also helps avoid a category of bugs related to closures implicitly capturing this. If you defined a closure in a build function on a StatefulWidget, that closure would implicitly capture this, which is the current widget instance